# Is there a way to Alias a dead network path to a local directory in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, batch-file, alias

I have a bunch of old Batch scripts that I may need to revive that have hundreds of references to a dead specific network path. Is there a way to alias `\\myNetWorkPath.com\SomeFolder\SomeFolder2` to a specific local Windows 7  directory?

For example, `\\myNetWorkPath.com\SomeFolder\SomeFolder2` alias to `C:\SomeFolder2`. 
Again, `\\myNetWorkPath.com\SomeFolder\SomeFolder2` is a dead (not working anymore) network path.

Please let me know if that doesn’t make any sense. 
Thanks!

Comment: Notepad - "Edit"-"Replace" ... "Replace All"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more details. There are 50 or so files, and some functions that actually build some of these sad network directories.  If aliasing is an option, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Pick a language and write a quick and dirty application that will change your code base.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. This is more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) kind of question, than for SO. You could try editing your hosts file to map the machine name to one that has the share name "SomeFolder" on it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my "Pick a language and write a quick and dirty application that will change your code base." comment... Here's a bit of c# that could get your going.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //foreach file you drop onto the compiled EXE
        foreach (string item in args)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(item))//if the file path actually exists
            {
                ChangeThePath(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ChangeThePath(string incomingFilePath)
    {
        string backupCopy = incomingFilePath + ".bck";
        System.IO.File.Copy(incomingFilePath, backupCopy);//make a backup
        string newPath = "c:\\This\\New\\Path\\Is\\Much\\Better";
        string oldPath = "c:\\Than\\This\\Deprecated\\One";
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(incomingFilePath))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(backupCopy))
            {
                string currentLine = string.Empty;
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(currentLine.Replace(oldPath, newPath));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but this doesn't technically answer the OP's question.